# Longitudinal study and the Dependent T-Test

Tags: t-test, panel-data, independence

A hypothetical: a vocational school measures satisfaction scores from its students on a yearly basis. Students graduate in less than a year so the students that are being questioned are not the same batch of students from one year to another but the demographical characteristics are pretty constant. Is it proper to do a dependent t-test in this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

This would not be a longitudinal study, longitudinal studies involving taking the same variable over time [Longitudinal Study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitudinal_study).

The rest depends on how you want to structure your study.  I would imagine that you're investigating if the new graduating class is either significantly lower or higher than the baseline of all graduating classes previous.

The population would be in this case, all of the students who had graduated before the current year.  The sample would be the students who are graduating this year.  Your null hypothesis would be that there is no difference in mean satisfaction score.  The alternative hypothesis would be there is a significant difference in mean satisfaction score at a certain alpha level.  This study would involve a 2 sided t-test, degrees of freedom being the sample size (N -1) or the graduating student class size who filled out the survey.